# Почему содержимое новой секции отображается на предыдущей секции?

Tags: html, css

Содержимое новой секции отображается на предыдущей секции. 
Вот html код новой и предыдущей секции:

```css
 #services {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 115px;
}

.title h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.sevices {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.sevices-item {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.sevices-item h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sevices-item p {
    color: #4A4848;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sevices-item:last-child {
    float: right;
}

.sevices-item:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Наши предложения
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Рекомендации по опросам</h3>
                <p>
                    Вы узнали, какие услуги оказывает риэлтор при покупке-продаже квартиры, аналогичный список у агентства недвижимости.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon2.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Помощь по продаже</h3>
                <p>
                    В риэлторской практике сопровождение покупки часто называют «подбором», т.к. специалист по недвижимости помогает быстро и точно подобрать объект недвижимости для покупателя.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon3.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Информационный сервис</h3>
                <p>
                    Фирма может гарантировать быстрый поиск жилища, т.к предлагает огромный выбор; дать рекомендации по выбору среди имеющихся в базе объектах.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Наши предложения
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Вот скрин: 
[image: Выделенный красным бордюром текст находится на предыдущей секции]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

особенности float-элементов. У вас `.sevices-item { float:left }` и `.sevices-item:last-child {float:right;}` . Добавьте родителю .seRvices {overflow:hidden} (и букву пропустили в названии класса в css) - заголовок перестанет переноситься. Пойдет, если не подразумевается наличие выступающих блоков в контейнере.

```css
 #services {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 115px;
}

.title h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.services {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.sevices-item {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.sevices-item h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sevices-item p {
    color: #4A4848;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sevices-item:last-child {
    float: right;
}

.sevices-item:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Наши предложения
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon1.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Рекомендации по опросам</h3>
                <p>
                    Вы узнали, какие услуги оказывает риэлтор при покупке-продаже квартиры, аналогичный список у агентства недвижимости.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon2.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Помощь по продаже</h3>
                <p>
                    В риэлторской практике сопровождение покупки часто называют «подбором», т.к. специалист по недвижимости помогает быстро и точно подобрать объект недвижимости для покупателя.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="sevices-item">
                <img src="img/icon3.png" alt="usluga" height="180" width="180">
                <h3>Информационный сервис</h3>
                <p>
                    Фирма может гарантировать быстрый поиск жилища, т.к предлагает огромный выбор; дать рекомендации по выбору среди имеющихся в базе объектах.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>
                Наши предложения
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```